# How to extract single array data from API which gives two arrays of output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am facing a problem, I can't extract data from just one array - temperature. I tried to put it into another array, but all I managed to do was put there all the data. Any advice? Thank you in advance!

> Console output of the function I use:
> {
> latitude: 51.75,
> longitude: 19.5,
> generationtime_ms: 0.28395652770996094,
> utc_offset_seconds: 0,
> timezone: 'GMT',
> timezone_abbreviation: 'GMT',
> elevation: 218,
> hourly_units: { time: 'iso8601', temperature_2m: '°C' },
> hourly: {
> time: [
> '2022-11-26T00:00', '2022-11-26T01:00', '2022-11-26T02:00',
> '2022-11-26T03:00', '2022-11-26T04:00', '2022-11-26T05:00',
> '2022-11-26T06:00', '2022-11-26T07:00', '2022-11-26T08:00',
> '2022-11-26T09:00', '2022-11-26T10:00', '2022-11-26T11:00',
> '2022-11-26T12:00', '2022-11-26T13:00', '2022-11-26T14:00',
> '2022-11-26T15:00', '2022-11-26T16:00', '2022-11-26T17:00',
> '2022-11-26T18:00', '2022-11-26T19:00', '2022-11-26T20:00',
> '2022-11-26T21:00', '2022-11-26T22:00', '2022-11-26T23:00',
> '2022-11-27T00:00', '2022-11-27T01:00', '2022-11-27T02:00',
> '2022-11-27T03:00', '2022-11-27T04:00', '2022-11-27T05:00',
> '2022-11-27T06:00', '2022-11-27T07:00', '2022-11-27T08:00',
> '2022-11-27T09:00', '2022-11-27T10:00', '2022-11-27T11:00',
> '2022-11-27T12:00', '2022-11-27T13:00', '2022-11-27T14:00',
> '2022-11-27T15:00', '2022-11-27T16:00', '2022-11-27T17:00',
> '2022-11-27T18:00', '2022-11-27T19:00', '2022-11-27T20:00',
> '2022-11-27T21:00', '2022-11-27T22:00', '2022-11-27T23:00',
> '2022-11-28T00:00', '2022-11-28T01:00', '2022-11-28T02:00',
> '2022-11-28T03:00', '2022-11-28T04:00', '2022-11-28T05:00',
> '2022-11-28T06:00', '2022-11-28T07:00', '2022-11-28T08:00',
> '2022-11-28T09:00', '2022-11-28T10:00', '2022-11-28T11:00',
> '2022-11-28T12:00', '2022-11-28T13:00', '2022-11-28T14:00',
> '2022-11-28T15:00', '2022-11-28T16:00', '2022-11-28T17:00',
> '2022-11-28T18:00', '2022-11-28T19:00', '2022-11-28T20:00',
> '2022-11-28T21:00', '2022-11-28T22:00', '2022-11-28T23:00',
> '2022-11-29T00:00', '2022-11-29T01:00', '2022-11-29T02:00',
> '2022-11-29T03:00', '2022-11-29T04:00', '2022-11-29T05:00',
> '2022-11-29T06:00', '2022-11-29T07:00', '2022-11-29T08:00',
> '2022-11-29T09:00', '2022-11-29T10:00', '2022-11-29T11:00',
> '2022-11-29T12:00', '2022-11-29T13:00', '2022-11-29T14:00',
> '2022-11-29T15:00', '2022-11-29T16:00', '2022-11-29T17:00',
> '2022-11-29T18:00', '2022-11-29T19:00', '2022-11-29T20:00',
> '2022-11-29T21:00', '2022-11-29T22:00', '2022-11-29T23:00',
> '2022-11-30T00:00', '2022-11-30T01:00', '2022-11-30T02:00',
> '2022-11-30T03:00',
> 68 more items
> ],
> temperature_2m: [
> 2.4,  2.3,  2.1,  1.9,  1.8,  1.7,  1.8,  1.7,  1.9,  2.3,  2.5,
> 2.6,  2.1,  1.1,  0.7,  0.5,  0.2,    0,  0.1,  0.1, -0.1, -0.1,
> -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.2,   -0,  0.1,    0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1,  0.2,
> 1,  1.5,    2,  2.1,  2.1,    2,  1.7,  1.5,  1.3,  1.2,  0.9,
> 0.9,  0.9,  0.7,  0.6,  0.2, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3,
> -0.4, -0.3,  0.4,  1.4,  1.8,  1.5,  1.4,  1.4,  0.9,  0.3,   -0,
> -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.3, -0.3, -0.5, -0.8, -0.9,   -1, -1.1, -1.3,
> -0.3, -0.3, -0.4, -0.5, -0.6, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.8, -0.9,
> -1,

As posted above, tried to extract one array from whole data asset

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

from what I can see here, its a nested object and not an array, have you tried

```
data.hourly.temperature_2m
```

this should give you the temperature_2m data, and if that does not work out, try checking typeof data if its a string or an object

Answer (score 0):

```
const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const axios = require('axios');
const API = 'https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=';
let array0 = [];
 
const getWeather = async() => {
    const [lat, lon] = [51.77, 19.47];
    const WeatherURI = `${API}${lat}&longitude=${lon}&hourly=temperature_2m`;
    const response = await axios.get(WeatherURI);
    console.log(response.data);
    const {temp_c} = (temperature_2m);
    array0 = response.data(temperature_2m)
    console.log(array0)
}
 
inquirer
    .prompt([
        {
            type: 'list',
            message: 'Select a location',
            name: 'source',
            choices: ['Lodz', 'Bialystok'],
        },
    ])
 
    .then(async (answers) => {
        const weather = await getWeather();
        switch(answers.source) {
            case 'Temperature in Lodz':
                console.log(weather[temp_c])
            break;
            default:
            console.error('Invalid Option!')
            break;
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
       console.error(err);
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.